# Regex optional with two matching groups

Tags: regex, performance

Make a regex that matches this:

`aaGrest` with  matching groups `[aa, G, rest]`

`bb` with matching groups `[bb]`

I am trying to make `Grest` part optional this doesn't work:

`^([a-z]{2}[a-z]?)[(P|G)(.*)]?`

Ps: dont complicate stuff or downvote!

Comment: you need **[(\[a-z\]{2})(?:(\[GP\])(\[a-z\]*))?](https://regex101.com/r/uV3tQ9/1)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([a-z]{2}[a-z]?)(?:(P|G)(.*))?
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/LdtnxlgbPm).

This uses a *non-capturing* group (syntax `(?:...)`) to group the optional part *without* forming a capturing group, which keeps the capturing groups numbered as 1, 2 and 3.

Square brackets form a *character class*, which isn't what you intended.

Comment: what's the difference between [non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) and square brackets?